# Two buttons to animate bottom drawer?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, slidingdrawer

I was hoping someone could help me to figure out how to create two buttons that perform the same action. Currently, I have a bottom drawer with a visible, clickable tab to open. I would like to create an additional button that performs the same action, but I'm not quite sure how to go about coding the JQuery function.

My current JQuery for the bottom drawer is below. I've also linked to a fiddle if it provides more context. [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/rs7bv59n/12/)

```
var h_bt = 0; //variable to keep track of the div#bottom condition.

    $('a#handler_bottom').on('click', function(event){  

        event.preventDefault();

        if(h_bt == 0){

            //$('div#bottom').animate({top:'600px'}, 300);
            //$('div#top').css({'background-color': 'red'});

            $(this).parent().animate({top:'480px'}, 300);
            $(this).css({'background-color': '#838da6'});

            h_bt = 1;
        }else{

            $(this).parent().animate({top:'600px'}, 300);
            $(this).css({'background-color': '#838da6'});

            h_bt = 0;
        }
    });
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you tell us which buttons should work in the same way and what would be the difference between the two if any?

Comment: Both the div_handler and the caldrop buttons would work in exactly the same way. They would both work to open and close the bottom drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and attach it to both the events:-

```
function repeatFunction(event){
 event.preventDefault();

    if(h_bt == 0){

        //$('div#bottom').animate({top:'600px'}, 300);
        //$('div#top').css({'background-color': 'red'});

        $(this).parent().animate({top:'480px'}, 300);
        $(this).css({'background-color': '#838da6'});

        h_bt = 1;
    }else{

        $(this).parent().animate({top:'600px'}, 300);
        $(this).css({'background-color': '#838da6'});

        h_bt = 0;
    }
```

}

2. Apply it to both the event like:-

   $(function(){
      $(element1).click(function(event){
         repeatFunction(event);
       });

   $(element2).click(function(event){
         repeatFunction(event);
      });
   });

Comment: Does this seem correct? It doesn't appear to be working for me

Comment: $(function(){ $('a#handler_bottom').click(function()(event){ repeatFunction(event); });

$('a#caldrop').click(function()(event){ repeatFunction(event); }); });

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo error. I have made the changes in my answer. It should be function(event) not function()(event). Please have a look.